# Table that spans whole body

Tags: html, css

I have a HTML page that just has a table in it that I would like to span the entire of the body and have scrollbars when it needs to scroll horizontally or vertically.

This is what I have for the styling of the table:

```css
table {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/kk8ga5d9/)

By default a table column will expand/shrink to fit the content (see my original jsfiddle). I want to maintain this behavior but allow for horizontal scrolling when there are too many columns and vertical scrolling when too many rows. The box shadow is to indicate the edges of the table which I want to be a minimum of 100% of the viewport (with scrollbars when it goes over)

As you can see, the table does not span the entire viewport - where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Could you possibly show a picture of your page as-is, and what you want it to look like when sufficient content is added that scrollbars should be available? Given your comments on Dippas' answer - and the likelihood I would have answered your question very similarly - it seems you either haven't explained yourself sufficiently, or we're understanding your requirements wrongly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `overflow` does not works on `table`...so you will need to wrap your table into two `div`...

**1**...The outer div `.wrapper` is for the `overflow:auto` if the table content is exceeded the viewport width

**2**...The inner div `.inner` is for having the `min-width` and `max-width` values equal to viewport width if content is lesser than viewport and then apply `display:inline-block` to that div so that it can extend its width if content is more than the viewport width

***Stack Snippet***

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

div.wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  overflow: auto;
}

div.inner {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 30px #000;
  font: 13px Verdana;
  display: inline-block;
  min-height: 100vh;
  min-width: 100vw;
  vertical-align: top;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="inner">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Id</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
        <td>Some Id</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The goes the closest to what I was after....I was actually hoping that the box shadow would show only on the very edges of the table, but with a minimum of 100% of the viewport (if that makes sense). So if the table was greater that 100% of the viewport on the horizontal, it wouldn't how the right box shadow until you scrolled across to the end of the table

Comment: @Cheetah I got your point what you are looking for...I updated my answer with explanation...Have a look...:)

Answer (score 0):

Add `height: 100vh;` **vh** is viewport height to the `<table>` tag in the CSS.

**EDIT**: use `overflow-y`

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: orange;
}

table {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: scroll;
}

td{
    background-color:red; 
    width: auto;
}

.box{
   overflow: scroll;
   height: 100vh;
   background-color: green;
   width: 15vw;
}

.text{ float:right;}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <table>
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>#1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>#2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>#3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>#4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>#5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>#6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>#7</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>#8</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>#9</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>#10</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>

<span class="text"> example text in background </span>
```

Hope this helps. The red background is so you can see the span of the cell. The orange background is the `body` and the `green` background is the parent tag of the table. You could add more columns if you like.

Comment: Does this help you? Ask any other thing.

Comment: This is not what I am after - I have edited the original question.

Comment: Is this what you were looking for? I've been a while working on it.

Answer (score 0):

**Hope this will help**

```css
table {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: grey;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000;
  overflow: auto; /* Scroll bar will add if it goes to long .. */
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Scroll bar will add if the content goes to long ..</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What does that do? How does it answer the question? Don't just blurt out code. Explain yourself! https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: @Rob, i did what i understand.